# Handsontable- The filter works wrong when using afterSelection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handsontable

We are facing an issue when useing `afterSelection` function, the filter has been unchecked:

The code is like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./handsontable.full.min.css">
<script src="./handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<div id='handsontable' style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>
<script>
    let container = document.getElementById('handsontable');
    let hot = new Handsontable(container, {
        colHeaders: true,
        data: [
            ['', 'Ford', 'Volvo', 'Toyota', 'Honda'],
            ['2016', 10, 11, 12, 13],
            ['2017', 20, 11, 14, 13],
            ['2018', 30, 15, 12, 13]
        ],
        filters: true,
        dropdownMenu: {
            items: {
                'filter_by_condition': {},
                'filter_by_value': {},
                'filter_action_bar': {}
            }
        },
        beforeFilter: function () {
        },
        afterFilter: function (obj) {
            console.log('afterFilter', JSON.stringify(obj));
        },
        afterSelection: function (obj) {
            hot.setDataAtCell(0, 0, 'new');
        }
    });

</script>
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on the filter button, untick on the checkbok
2. The result showed as expected but click on the filter button, all checkboxs were unchecked like this:

Could you please give us an advice to fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handsontable - Filter works incorrectly when using afterSelection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44534847/handsontable-filter-works-incorrectly-when-using-afterselection)